# Get name attribute of IO_Bufferedreader

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am wanting to do is use the name of the current file I have that is from a generator and use the first section of the name + append .csv

The buffered stream looks like this

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='data/20160107W FM0.xml'>
```

I am having an issue with this code:

```
for file_to_read in roots:
        print(file_to_read)
        base = os.path.basename(file_to_read)
        print(base)
        name_to_write = os.path.splitext(file_to_read)[0]
        outname = str(name_to_write[0]) + ".csv"
        outdir = "output"
        with open(os.path.join(outdir, outname), 'w', newline='') as csvf:
```

I receive this error which I believe means I am trying to split the stream rather than the name attribute of the buffered stream. Which leads me to this error.

```
$ python race.py data/ -e .xml
<_io.BufferedReader name='data/20160107W FM0.xml'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "race.py", line 106, in <module>
    data_attr(rootObs)
  File "race.py", line 40, in data_attr
    base = os.path.basename(file_to_read)
  File "C:\Users\Sayth\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 232, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\Sayth\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in split
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Users\Sayth\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 139, in splitdrive
    if len(p) >= 2:
TypeError: object of type '_io.BufferedReader' has no len()
```

My expected output is:

```
20160107W FM0.csv
```

Comment: Well then access its `name` attribute: `os.path.basename(file_to_read.name)`

Comment: Thanks was reading the docs but couldn't see a reference example on how to do that

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO.name

Comment: Yes that's the one i read it references th ed "name" 11 times but never actually shows you can access it with .name . All good though thats why we have SO.  This wasn't directly here either, small example slipped through cracks of both..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for a file you are reading/writing this works:

```
filepath = '../data/test.txt'

with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
    print(file)  # -> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='../data/test.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
    print(file.name)  # -> ../data/test.txt
```

but the `type` here is `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='../data/test.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>` so i am not entirely sure how you open your file or get a `_io.BufferedReader`.

i assume they are both derived from [`io.FileIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO) and should therefore have a `.name` attribute.

thanks to *Ashwini Chaudhary*'s comment, i can recreate your exact situation:

```
from io import BufferedReader

filepath = '../data/test.txt'

with BufferedReader(open(filepath, 'r')) as file:
    print(file)  # -> <_io.BufferedReader name='../data/test.txt'>
    print(file.name)  # -> ../data/test.txt
```

Comment: `file.buffer` or `io.BufferedReader(file)` will give you `_io.BufferedReader`.